# Вызов метода у объекта вектора! Java!

Tags: vector, java

**Здравствуйте, уважаемые хэшкодеры!**

Требуется ваша помощь в решении, надеюсь, тривиальной задачи.
Как вызвать методы у элемента вектора? 
То есть имеется vector класса Vector, в котором лежат элементы типа Type.
Причем у класса Type есть метод getName(). 
Но когда я хочу выполнить вот такую операцию, вектор ругается:
vector.get(1).getName(); - IDEA подчеркивает красным цветом вызов метода getName();
Как это обойти, кто знает?

**Спасибо!**

Comment: Покажите, как объявлен ваш `vector`. Тут какая-та тривиальная ошибка. Или лучше, выложите **минимальный** пример, воспроизводящий проблему.

Comment: Обойти это очень просто: вам нужно привести возвращаемое значение метода `get` к нужному типу. Для этого вы должны использовать либо обычную операцию приведения типа, либо параметризовать ваш экземпляр вектора.

Comment: @a_gura, вместо того, чтобы кастить значение к нужному типу, лучше использовать Generics.

Comment: @VeLKerr "параметризовать ваш экземпляр вектора" - это и есть "использовать Generics".

Answer (score 1):

Наверное Ваш вектор объявлен  так:

```
Vector vector = new Vector();
```

В этом случае, каждый элемент вектора считается объектом класса `Object`, а значит для него Ваши методы неприменимы.
Используйте [`Generics`](http://www.quizful.net/post/java-generics-tutorial) (если, конечно, Вы не работаете с версией Java < 1.5).
С помощью `Generics` объявление вектора можно переписать так:

```
Vector<Type> vector = new Vector<Type>(); //Java 1.5, 1.6
Vector<Type> vector = new Vector<>(); //Java 1.7
```

Я привёл здесь 2 версии: для Java 1.5, 1.6 и для 1.7. Как видите, в Java 1.7 был добавлен оператор **diamond** `<>`, что ещё больше упростило код.

Ещё 1 совет: пользуйтесь ArrayList вместо Vector. Он быстрее и вообще новее: [Отличие Vector от ArrayList](http://www.quizful.net/interview/java/vector-arraylist-difference).